# How to import API data using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull some data from EIA API, below is what I tried but I'm getting the error on the first line of code:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
call_eia = requests.get = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/nuclear-outages/facility-nuclear-outages/data?api_key=XXXXXXXX'
data_eia=pd.read_csv(StringIO(call_eia.text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't requested anything from the API. Look carefully at your first line:

```
call_eia = requests.get = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/nuclear-outages/facility-nuclear-outages/data?api_key=XXXXXXXX'
#        ^              ^
```

There are 2 `=` signs, so what you're really doing is assigning the URL string to both your `call_eia` variable and the `get` attribute of the `requests` module, overwriting the function that was there originally. Then, when you try to pass `call_eia` to `pd.read_csv()`, instead of passing a `requests` object, you're just passing a string, the URL.

Try

```
call_eia = requests.get('https://api.eia.gov/v2/nuclear-outages/facility-nuclear-outages/data?api_key=XXXXXXXX')
```

instead and your code should work.

Comment: I tried that and i'm now getting a different error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".                          Also for some reason the first line of code is coming in a string.

Comment: @AVad Make sure you didn't do the same thing earlier in your code. You can also put the line `print(type(requests.get))` just before the `call_eia = ...` line. It should print out `<class 'function'>`. If it prints `<class 'str'>`, something has gone wrong earlier in the code.

Comment: Thanks! I found the same issue earlier in the code!